# Kibana not picking up records with @timestamp field

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have the following JSON log that I am feeding into logstash and outputting into ElasticSearch. When the "@timestamp" is in the log, the record does not appear in Kibana. However, when I rename the JSON field in the log to "timestamp" (remove the @) it works. How can I fix this so that it properly picks up entries with the @timestamp field? Thanks.

JSON Log:

```
    {
    "@timestamp": "2017-02-14T15:55:05.070Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "action": "create",
    "controller": "MyController",
    "db": 10.51,
    "duration": 40.77,
    "format": "json",
    "message": "[200] POST /api/mycontroller (MYCONTROLLER#create)",
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "/api/mycontroller",
    "remote_ip": "55.11.99.000",
    "status": 200,
    "user_id": 8888,
    "view": 12.91
}
```

logstash.conf

```
  input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically how this is done is to put the timestamp from the source into a field that isn't `@timestamp` and then [add a `date { }` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) to turn that field into the `@timestamp` value there.

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", ISO8601 ]
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "timestamp" ]
  }
}
```

It seems odd to do this in post-processing, but Logstash likes it that way. The `mutate {}` gets rid of the extra timestamp field, so it won't show up in your ES documents.

Comment: Can this be configured globally? Use case: mobile app is source of timestamps. App have offline mode. Kibana timestamp is useless to harmful. Global config change would solve UX for all dashboards/reports.

Comment: @przemo_li Absolutely! As written, the above would apply to *everything*. To not apply to everything, it would need to be wrapped in an `if {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Kibana`, does create a *@timestamp* field for itself by default to index the events. So since you're having a field with the same name, `Kibana` is trying to override it with the browser's time.

So what you could do is as @sysadmin1138 suggested, **mutate** the *@timestamp* field by replacing the value into a new field and the remove the existing *@timestamp* so that you it won't get overridden.

If you wish you could still have the *@timestamp* field, as long as you've replaced it with a new field. In that case you might be having two timestamps, one the default `Kibana`'s *@timestamp* plus the new timestamp field you created so that you'll have the freedom to index the events as you wish based on the timestamp you need.